# Is it possible to create a memory-efficient VLA-like type that can be returned by value?

Tags: c++

I was wondering if it's possible in C++ to create a type that works like a VLA (stack-allocated, variable sized), can also be returned from a function, and doesn't waste memory like a linear allocator.

Could be used like:

```
// Fibonacci sequence
stack_array<int> fib(size_t n) {

  stack_array<int> f(n);
  f[0] = 0;
  f[1] = 1;
  for(size_t i=2;i<n;++i) {
    f[i] = f[i-1] + f[i-2];
  }

  return f;
}
```

This is useful because I find myself returning variable sized things (usually using `std::vector`) with heap allocation. I might also like to do this in a real-time context where heap allocation isn't allowed. Functional-stye programming on audio buffers, say. But mostly, this is an intellectual exercise to see what's possible.

I realize that I can write a `std::allocator` which would do linear allocation, thus satisfying a realtime constraint, and easily supporting nontrivial types, but this has the downside of wasting memory. I'm wondering if I can do better.

To make this more concrete, suppose we have:

```
thread_local arena myArena; // I don't want to have to pass this around!

std::vector<float> f() {
   return std::vector<float, arena>(64, myArena);
}

std::vector<float> g() {
   return std::vector<float, arena>(64, myArena);
}

void main() {

   {
       auto a = f();
   }

   {
       auto b = g();
   }

   // At this point, we still have 128*sizeof(float) allocated.
   // You might say to use multiple arenas, but that might not
   // be easy.
}
```

Now, we know that if we aren't returning things from functions, then LIFO construction/destruction order is guaranteed (this is needed for RAII). I'm wondering if constraints can be placed on the container so it can be returned from a function while still guaranteeing LIFO order.

Here's my attempt at an implementation, using a separate `thread_local` stack, but I don't know if it's really correct, as I find ensuring the construction and destruction order maintains the invariants a bit confusing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// Big stack.
static size_t stackSize = 1024*1024*10;
static thread_local uint8_t* start = nullptr;
static thread_local uint8_t* stack = nullptr;

// An array with simple stack based allocation.
// Size is fixed on creation.
//
// I'm assuming this is difficult with std::vector
// and a custom allocator because it can grow.
// 
// T must be trivial for now
template<class T>
class stack_array {

    size_t _size;
    T* ptr;

public:

    stack_array(size_t size) : _size(size) {
        static_assert(std::is_trivial<T>::value);
        if(stack == nullptr) {
            start = stack = (uint8_t*) malloc(stackSize);
        }
        ptr = (T*) stack;
        stack += size*sizeof(T);
        assert(stack < start + stackSize);
        printf("ctor %p, stack %d\n", (void*) this, int(stack - start));
    }

    // I think the copy constructor violates our stack
    // nesting property, since the lifetimes overlap.
    stack_array(const stack_array&) = delete;

    ~stack_array() {
        stack -= _size*sizeof(T);
        printf("dtor %p, stack %d\n", (void*) this, int(stack - start));
    }

    stack_array& operator=(const stack_array& a) {
        printf("assign\n");
        assert(_size == a._size);
        for(size_t i=0;i<_size;++i) {
            ptr[i] = a.ptr[i];
        }
        return *this;
    }

    // Is this actually correct?
    stack_array(stack_array&& other) {
        printf("move\n");
        ptr = other.ptr;
        _size = other._size;
        other._size = 0;
    }

    T& operator[](size_t i) { assert(i < _size); return ptr[i]; }
    const T& operator[](size_t i) const { assert(i < _size); return ptr[i]; }

    size_t size() const { return _size; }
};

// Fibonacci sequence
stack_array<int> fib(size_t n) {

    stack_array<int> f(n);
    f[0] = 0;
    f[1] = 1;
    for(size_t i=2;i<n;++i) {
        f[i] = f[i-1] + f[i-2];
    }

    return f;
}

template<class T, class F>
void foreach(const stack_array<T> &a, F f) {
    for(size_t i=0;i<a.size();++i) {
        f(a[i]);
    }
}

template<class T, class F>
auto map(const stack_array<T> &a, F f) {
    stack_array< decltype(f(T())) > r(a.size());
    for(size_t i=0;i<a.size();++i) {
        r[i] = f(a[i]);
    }
    return r;
}

template<class T, class F>
auto filter(const stack_array<T> &a, F f) {
    stack_array<int> b(a.size());
    size_t n = 0;
    for(size_t i=0;i<a.size();++i) {
        if(f(a[i])) {
            b[n++] = i;
        }
    }
    stack_array<T> r(n);
    for(size_t i=0;i<n;++i) {
        r[i] = a[b[i]];
    }
    return r;
}

template<class T> void printArray(const stack_array<T> &a) {
    foreach(a, [](T t){ std::cout << t << std::endl;});
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    {
        stack_array<int> a = fib(20);
        printArray(a);
        printArray(map(a, [](int i) { return i+1; }));
        printArray(filter(a, [](int i) { return i%2; }));

        stack_array<int> b(a.size());
        b = a;
    }
    assert(stack == start);

}
```

Comment: What does `stack_array` do? Please post the code here, not via a link.

Comment: I'm tempted to say that this isn't possible with the C++ stack if the callee gets to choose the VLA size, but the caller specifies the size of the stack frame. Your stack-based approach just seems like a limited allocator that's working on its own heap, and can't do allocations that aren't strictly LIFO.

Comment: Copy and move operations should not consider the actual `ptr` and `size` members to be part of the value of the `stack_array`. Those are intrinsically linked to the memory location of each instance. You need to copy or move the elements instead. Edit : For example the copy constructor would look like your copy assignment operator.

Comment: @Taylor Noted. To expand on my previous comment, since you only use trivial types, and you can't actually just move the pointers around, both move and copy operations will result in the same thing. It's just a `memcpy` to different locations in the allocated space.

Comment: You can probably still use `std::vector`, but supply a [stack based allocator, like this one](http://howardhinnant.github.io/stack_alloc.html)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie. That's a linear allocator which happens to be on a stack. Different thing, but definitely useful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking briefly at your stack-based approach, it seems like nothing more than a heap-based allocator working on its own little private heap, but with a strict limitation wherein it malfunctions if allocations are not performed in strictly LIFO order. At that rate, you might consider extending this to actually support non-trivial types while keeping the same allocation mechanism.

With that said, it also doesn't appear to maintain its preconditions under normal-seeming use: `filter` constructs `b` then `r`, but `r` seemingly outlives `b` (discovered with ASAN by manually poisoning and unpoisoning bits of your "stack" in the ctor and dtor).

If memory is not too tight, you could consider using an [arena allocator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Region-based_memory_management). You could either maintain small arenas that (as an explicit requirement to the user, or through reference-counting) outlive any allocations made into them.

You also might want to consider more traditional methods of returning values, such as allocating stack-based arrays in the caller and passing pointers/references to them. At least for the audio application, fixed-length buffers might also be suitable.

Comment: I don't believe a general purpose allocator (satisfying `std::allocator`, say) can use a stack.

Comment: @Taylor Yeah, after reading the spec you're right and I'll edit shortly. That said, given the requirements I'm a bit confused now given the state of the question which is hindering further development of this answer--are you looking for an alternative to what you have, or a code review addressing your existing solution?

Comment: Thanks for your answer :). I'm not looking for a code review actually. Just wondering if it's possible. I included the code to make the question more concrete.

Comment: @Taylor As it stands, not too sure because we might have differing definitions. It looks like you're passing around (by value) a minimal wrapper around an off-stack region used as a VLA (and I'm still fighting with my compilers' sanitizers to validate that it does so correctly). If I were implementing something with these requirements I might consider using an arena instead, and passing lightweight references into that arena by value as much as possible.

Comment: @Taylor After instrumenting your code with ASan, I'm getting at least one memory violation regarding ctor/dtor order with `filter`: `r` (the returned value) outlives `b` and no move ctor is ever called on it (RVO I think); as a result invariants *are* broken since the order is b, r, ~b, ~r. There's a possibility of making this work, but so far this problem suggests that the current design is too complex and brittle and might want to be reworked to require less of users (i.e. using the arena as I mentioned, and reclaiming memory in one pass at the end)

Comment: Thanks again. I'm a bit embarrassed that I didn't try Asan! (I use it all the time for my app)